# How to remove double quote square bracket & single quote?

Tags: ansible

I am getting below output from ansible variable, but i want to to store only domain-c39

```
 output:  "['domain-c39']"
  expected output: domain-c39
```

How can i do this ? any input?

here is the playbook,

```
- name: Get cluster MOD
  uri:
    url: https://192.168.200.224/rest/vcenter/cluster?filter.names=test-clr
    force_basic_auth: yes
    validate_certs: no
    headers:
      Cookie: "{{ login.set_cookie }}"
  register: cluster_id

- name: store moid for required cluster
  shell: echo "{{ cluster_id | json_query('json.value[*].cluster') }}"
  register: cluster_moid
```

And here is the output,

```
TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "changed": true,
        "cmd": "echo \"['domain-c39']\"",
        "delta": "0:00:00.002944",
        "end": "2020-05-13 18:22:43.316235",
        "failed": false,
        "rc": 0,
        "start": "2020-05-13 18:22:43.313291",
        "stderr": "",
        "stderr_lines": [],
        "stdout": "['domain-c39']",
        "stdout_lines": [
            "['domain-c39']"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: You would need to show us your playbook. How are you setting that value in the first place?

Comment: i have added the playbook & output

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to be using `echo` in `shell` task; you can just use `set_fact` to create a new variable with your desired content:

```
    - name: store moid for required cluster
      set_fact:
        cluster_moid: "{{ cluster_id | json_query('json.value[*].cluster') }}"
```

This creates a new `cluster_moid` variable with the value you want.

Comment: after setting the variable then also getting out put ok: [localhost] => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "cluster_moid": [
            "domain-c39"
        ]
    },
    "changed": false
}   i want to only this value to get stored in variable domain-c39

Comment: Then you'll need to update your question to show exactly what the content of your `cluster_id` variable looks like, because without that information I'm just guessing.